# How to push object in array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have array

```
var CatTitle = ['Travel', 'Daily Needs','Food & Beverages','Lifestyle','Gadget & Entertainment','Others']
```

i want to push an object into this array

```
var myObj = {Coupon exp : 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'}
```

and i ll i have new array like this

```
var CatTitle = [
'Travel': [{Coupon exp : 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'},{Coupon exp : 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'}], 
'Daily Needs',
'Food & Beverages',
'Lifestyle',
'Gadget & Entertainment',
'Others']
```

How i can do it? Thanks

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid JavaScript, so it's unclear what you're actually asking for.

Comment: search array.push(). your question shows you didnt do any research effort.

Comment: This question has 4 answers in under 20 minutes and it asks for something that does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think like this:

```
var CatTitle = ['Travel', 'Daily Needs','Food & Beverages','Lifestyle','Gadget & Entertainment','Others'];
var myObj = {Coupon exp : 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'};
var newObject = {};
var newArray = [];

var i;
for(i=0; i < CatTitle.length; i++) {
   var dump = {
      CatTitle[i]: myObj 
   }
   newArray.push(dump);
}
newObject = newArray;
```

Comment: i see..can you try this "CartTitle[i].toString()"

Answer (score 1):

> How to push an object in an Array

```
const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

animals.push({animal: 'cows'});

console.log(animals); // ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", { animal: "cows" }]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can filter `Travel` because it is type of `string`, and then just push desired object into array:

```js
let catTitle = ['Travel', 'Daily Needs','Food & Beverages','Lifestyle','Gadget & Entertainment','Others'];

catTitle = catTitle.filter(f => f !=='Travel');
catTitle.push({Travel:{'Coupon exp': 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'}})
console.log(catTitle)
```

If `CatTitle` were an [Object](http://illa.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

```
var CatTitle = {'Travel': 0, 'Daily Needs': 0,'Food & Beverages': 0,'Lifestyle': 0,
    'Gadget & Entertainment': 0,'Others': 0}
```

Then it would be fairly simple:

```
CatTitle.Travel = {'Coupon exp': 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I seriously do not know what you intend to do or where you are heading but below code will eventually do what you want.

> Just using the only fact that Javascript Arrays are objects
>   internally.

```js
var CatTitle = ['Travel', 'Daily Needs', 'Food & Beverages', 'Lifestyle', 'Gadget & Entertainment', 'Others']

var myObj = {Couponexp : 'xxx', couponcode : 'xxx'}
CatTitle.shift();

CatTitle["Travel"] = [];

CatTitle["Travel"].push(myObj);
CatTitle["Travel"].push(myObj);

console.log(CatTitle);
console.log(CatTitle.Travel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you confusing `Array` and `Object`. To easily explain I'm going to use literal syntax.

Arrays are represented by `[]`.

> Arrays doesn't have keys, so you can't use like that. Arrays keys are dynamically ordered index.

```
var CatTitle = [
    'Travel', 
    'Daily Needs',
    'Food & Beverages',
    'Lifestyle',
    'Gadget & Entertainment',
    'Others',
]
```

And Objects are represented by `{}`.

```
var myObj = {
    exp : 'xxx', 
    couponcode : 'xxx',
}
```

If you'd like to push some object into the array, use `CatTitle.push({ exp: 'xxx' })`. So that you will have an array like this.

```
var CatTitle = [
    'Travel', 
    'Daily Needs',
    'Food & Beverages',
    'Lifestyle',
    'Gadget & Entertainment',
    'Others',
    { exp: 'xxx' }, // <-- you pushed here at last index (6)
];

CatTitle[6] // { exp: 'xxx' }
```

But I believe that you're looking for an object of objects. Like this:

```
var CatTitle = {
    'Travel': [{ exp: 'xxx' }, { exp: 'yyy' }], 
    'Daily Needs': [],
    'Food & Beverages': [],
    'Lifestyle': [],
    'Gadget & Entertainment': [],
    'Others': [],
};

CatTitle['Travel'] // [{ exp: 'xxx' }, { exp: 'xxx' }]
CatTitle['Travel'][0] // { exp: 'xxx' }
```

I see that you're starting learning JavaScript. I recommend you to read the docs about [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

Other commendation is about semantic, never create variables in capital. Avoid creating keys as string, but I believe that you want it like something dynamic, in this case ok.

A good example:

```
var catTitles = {
    'Travel': [{ exp: 'xxx' }, { exp: 'yyy' }], 
    'Daily Needs': [],
    'Food & Beverages': [],
    'Lifestyle': [],
    'Gadget & Entertainment': [],
    'Others': [],
};

catTitles['Travel'] // [{ exp: 'xxx' }, { exp: 'xxx' }]
catTitles['Travel'][0] // { exp: 'xxx' }


// you can add another category like this
catTitle['Restaurants'] = [{ exp: 'xxx' }];
```